# How do I turn a javascript ajax caller function into async/await?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following function `getData`

```
getData = (param) => {
    // jquery
    $.ajax(...).done(..)
}
```

How do I turn `getData` into a blocking function so that `refreshPage` only gets called after the ajax within `getData` is done?

```
data = getData(..)
refreshPage()
```

Please note: I don't want to pass `refreshPage` into the ajax callback within `getData`

OK... here is what I tried and seems working:

```
getData = (param) => {
    // jquery
    return $.ajax(...).done(..)
}
getData.then(refreshPage())
```

Comment: `getData` cannot be a blocking function, unless you make AJAX synchronous (which is a very bad idea). `await getData(...)` can be made quasi-blocking, if the containing function is `async` (by making `getData` return a promise). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Just wrap it in a `Promise` that resolves when you get the data?

Comment: @jhpratt There's no point in wrapping it in promise, `$.ajax` already returns a perfectly nice one (assuming `$` is jQuery).

Comment: And given no mention of jQuery, I haven't assumed that. Conversion from a `Promise` to `async`/`await` certainly has a million dupes by itself.

Comment: sorry forgot to mention it's jquery

Comment: I mean, `$`, followed by `ajax` followed by `done` is highly likely to be jQuery or jQuery-like

Comment: Assuming $.ajax() is jQuery is a pretty straightforward assumption @jhpratt. Simply using `async / await` should do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getData = (param) => {
    // jquery
    return $.ajax(...);
}

async test() {
    var x = await getData()
    console.log(x)
}
```

Comment: This is pretty close to what I have tried,which I used `getData().then(..)`, I cannot verify if using `await getData()` because webpack throws error on me.

Answer (score 1):

```
getData = (param) => $.ajax(...).done(..)

getData().done(() => refreshPage())
// or
getData().done(refreshPage)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
function getData (param)
{
   ...........       
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
        jQuery.ajax({...});
   });
}
...........

getData(param).then(()=>refreshPage());
```

Comment: The combination of this answer and @Zlv Ben-Or is working.

Answer (score 0):

you should return a promise from your get data method

```
getData = (param) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   }
}
```

then when things are done in ajax
called `resolve(data)` there

Comment: Please read the comments. The method already returns a promise.

Comment: Let me it if it is cleared to you or I post the proper code